# How to assign translated value to a text variable in array in Angular

Tags: angular, translate, subscribe

I have wizardStep array which consists from a path and text. I need to have this text translated using `translateService`.

```
steps: WizardStep[] = [
    {path: 'agreement-closing', text: 'Confirm'},
    {path: 'agreement-closed', text: 'Result'},
  ];
```

`translate.instant` doesn't work as it returns key because it is not loaded yet.
And how to assign `translate.get('Confirm').subscribe(text => ???)` to `text` value I'm not sure. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Made the steps array empty on initialization and in `ngOnInit()` created something like this:

```
this.translate.get('Confirm').subscribe(word => this.steps.push({path: 'agreement-closing', text:word}));
```

Works fine for me.